# How do I select everything after a certain position using REGEXP in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, xregexp

I am using Oracle 11G and I have the following string:  `I - Am in- Need Help- Please` and want to parse the string using the `-` character then select everything after the second object.  I have been playing around with `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `SUBSTR` and I can select the second object but can't seem to select everything after the second object.  I know I need to add a * somewhere I think but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('I - Am in- Need of Help- Please', '[^-]+' , 1, 2) 
  FROM DUAL;
```

The above query returns the second object 'Am in' but I want this returned 'Need of Help- Please'. It is also important to note that I don't want the `-` character directly following the second object in the result either but I want to start with the third object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `[^-]` will only match non-hyphen characters, your match group will start after the first hyphen and then stop before the next one.  To capture everything following the first hyphen, try:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR ('I - Am in- Need of Help- Please', '-.+' , 1), '-', '', 1, 1) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This answer gives me the following  'Am in Need of Help Please' but I want to get everything after the second '-' and get this 'Need of Help- Please'.  Also I don't want to get rid of every '-' character just the one in front of the second matched object.